# Stuck on minmax algorithm with alpha beta pruning

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, minimax, minmax

I'm trying to implement a minmax algorithm with alpha beta pruning in a tic tac toe game in java. When I finish to coding it I immediately found an exception of `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` so I tried to put some Terminal output to find the error by myself and I discovered that it was caused by a wrong result in the final return: the algorithm finally returns `[-1][-1]` with score `-2147483646` and it cause an exception when the rest of the code try to make the move and put the coordinates in the field. I made some scheme to simulate some moves and some possible tree but I can't find the bug.

```
   /*
   * int field[][] is the board array, it may contains 0(empty), 1(opponent's seed), 2(computer's seed)
   * nComputer = 2 (computer's seed)
   * nPlayer = 1 (opponent's seed)
   * computerMove = new int[3]
   * remainingMoves has been calculated before the main call
   */

   // Main call
   computerMove = cMove(remainingMoves, nComputer,Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
   field[computerMove[1]][computerMove[2]] = nComputer; // This line cause the exception!!
   // MinMax alpha-beta pruning algorithm
   private static int[] cMove(int depth, int player, int alpha, int beta) {

       int[][] moveList = new int[3][10];
       moveList = generateMoves(field); // See below for details

       int temp;
       int score;
       int bestR = -1;
       int bestC = -1;

       // check function retunrns 1(opponent wins), 2(computer wins), 0(draw) or -1(nothing)
       if(moveList[0][0] == 0 || depth == 0) {
           score = cScore(player);

           return new int[] { score, bestR, bestC };
       } else {
           for (int i = 1;i < moveList[0][0]; i++) {
               // Trying to make a move
               field[moveList[1][i]][moveList[2][i]] = player;

               if(player == nComputer) { // Maximazing player
                   score = cMove(depth -1, nPlayer, alpha, beta)[0];
                   if(score > alpha) {
                       alpha = score;
                       bestR = moveList[1][i];
                       bestC = moveList[2][i];
                   } 
               } else { // Minimizing player
                   score = cMove(depth -1, nComputer, alpha, beta)[0];
                   if(score < beta) {
                       beta = score;
                       bestR = moveList[1][i];
                       bestC = moveList[2][i];
                   } 
               }

               field[moveList[1][i]][moveList[2][i]] = 0; // Undo move
               if(alpha >= beta) i = 10; // Cut-off
           }

           if(player == nComputer) temp = alpha; 
           else temp = beta;

           return new int[] { temp, bestR, bestC };

       }
   }

   /*
   * generateMoves function returns an array 3x10 where [0][0] is the number
   * of possible moves and [0,1,2][1-9] are the score and the
   * coordinates(rows and columns) of all the possible moves
   */
   private static int[][] generateMoves(int[][] field) {
       int[][] result = new int[3][10];
       int k = 0;

       if(check(4) != -1) {
           return result;
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < field[0].length; j++) {
               if (field[i][j] == 0) {
                   k++;
                   result[1][k] = i;
                   result[2][k] = j;
               }
           }
       }

       result[0][0] = k;

       return result;
   }

   // cScore function assign a score for the actual node with an heuristic evaluation
private static int cScore(int p) {
    int score = 0;
    score += cRow(p, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2);
    score += cRow(p, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    score += cRow(p, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2);
    score += cRow(p, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0);
    score += cRow(p, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1);
    score += cRow(p, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2);
    score += cRow(p, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2);
    score += cRow(p, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0);
    return score;
 }

private static int cRow(int player, int rOne, int cOne, int rTwo, int cTwo, int rThr, int cThr) {
    int score = 0;

    if (field[rOne][cOne] == nComputer) {
        score = 1;
    } else if (field[rOne][cOne] == nPlayer) {
        score = -1;
    }

    if (field[rTwo][cTwo] == nComputer) {
        if (score == 1) {
            score = 10;
        } else if (score == -1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (field[rTwo][cTwo] == nPlayer) {
        if (score == -1) {
            score = -10;
        } else if (score == 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = -1;
        }
    }

    if (field[rThr][cThr] == nComputer) {
        if (score > 0) {
            score *= 10;
        } else if (score < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (field[rThr][cThr] == nPlayer) {
        if (score < 0) {
            score *= 10;
        } else if (score > 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = -1;
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

I'm stuck on this problem for one week and I'm going crazy!
Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english but it isn't my main language and I slowly trying to learn it

-----------------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------

Adding check function as requested:

```
// check function first check the state of 5 cells that needs to be filled to won([0,0][0,1][0,2][1,0][2,0])
public static int check(int nMove) {
    int state = -1;

    if(field[0][0] != 0) {
        state = col(0,1);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on first col
        state = row(0,1);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on first row
        state = diagonal(1);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on first diagonal
    }
    if (field[0][1] != 0) {
        state = col(1,2);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on second col
    }
    if (field[0][2] != 0) {
        state = col(2,3);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on third col
        state = diagonal(2);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on second diagonal
    }
    if (field[1][0] != 0) {
        state = row(1,2);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on second row
    }
    if (field[2][0] != 0) {
        state = row(2,3);
        if(state == 1 || state == 2) return state; // Win on third row
    }

    if(nMove == 8) return 0; // Draw

    return state;
}
// Check if the entire row is filled (check rows from starting to n points)
private static int row(int start, int n) {
    int s = -1;
    int k = 0;
    int h = 0;

    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (field[0]).length; j++) {
            if(field[i][j] == 1) {
                k++;
                if(k==3) s = 1;
            } else if(field[i][j] == 2) {
                    h++;
                    if(h==3) s = 2;
            }
        }
        k=0;
        h=0;
    }

    return s;
}
// Check if the entire col is filled (check cols from starting to n points)
private static int col(int start, int n) {
    int s = -1;
    int k = 0;
    int h = 0;

    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (field).length; j++) {
            if(field[j][i] == 1) {
                k++;
                if(k==3) s = 1;
            } else if(field[j][i] == 2) {
                    h++;
                    if(h==3) s = 2;
            }
        }
        k=0;
        h=0;
    }

    return s;
}
// Check if the entire diagonal is filled (check first diagonal if n=1 and second diagonal if n=2)
private static int diagonal(int n) {
    int s = -1;
    int k = 0;
    int h = 0;

    if(n == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (field).length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            if(field[i][j]== 1) {
                k++;
                if(k==3) s = 1;
            } else if(field[i][j] == 2) {
                h++;
                if(h==3) s = 2;
            }
        }
    } else if (n == 2) {
        int j = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < (field).length; i++) {
            if(field[i][j] == 1) {
                k++;
                if(k==3) s = 1;
            }
            else if(field[i][j] == 2) {
                h++;
                if(h==3) s = 2;
            }
            j--;
        }
    } else { }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ill work on this answer for you, but can you give me all of your classes? There is a lot of stuff missing and I have no idea what it is. Just copy and paste them all in. Let me know if you imported any jars, or anything like that as well.

Comment: The entire code for this test is very long (about 1k lines) so to make easier to understand it I decided to share only the interested part. This function it's part of a class called IA and I compiled it successfully. But the entire algorithm result is always [-1][-1] with a score of about 2 * 10^9. This let me think there's a problem in the recursion but I can't understand where. If it can be helpful I can post also the check algorithm and if necessary also the entire code but I think it can only confuse. Thanks for the very quick answer

Comment: Use the debugger. If you know the glitch and what it your code should be doing then the debugger will actually give you the values while you run the code step by step. There is just no way I can do this in my head.

Comment: I found the part of the code that generate the exception but being this recursive it's so hard to debug and I can't found the cause that makes it always return `[-1][-1]` with score `2147483646`

Comment: The final result suggests that "cMove" is called only one time, for that, the line `if (check(8 - depth) != -1 || depth == 0) {` is suspicious. could you post "check" method?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your board is larger than 3x3, otherwise tick-tack-toe with 4 as a winning condition does not make too much sense, your exception will be caused here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < field[0].length; j++) {
           if (field[i][j] == 0) {
               k++;
               result[1][k] = i; // out of bounds
               result[2][k] = j; // out of bounds
           }
       }
   }
```

For a field with size A x B, when the board is empty, k will become as big as `A*B - 1`. For `A = B = 7` this would become 48, which is larger than 9, which is the max index allowed in `result[i]`.

// ======================= EDIT =================================
I'm a bit confused and not sure, what you are trying to optimize (best score for the computer or player?) but I found something that explains the result.

In each recursive call you have a variable `player`.
Based on its value you update `alpha` or `beta`.
At the end of the recursive step you return `alpha` or `beta` based on the value of `player`.
But, you update `alpha` if `player == 2`

```
if(player == 2) { // Maximazing player
    score = cMove(depth -1, nPlayer, alpha, beta)[0];
    if(score > alpha) {
```

But return `beta` if `player == 2`

```
if(player == 1) temp = alpha;
    else temp = beta;
```

So you always return `MIN_VALUE + 1` for `alpha` or `MAX_VALUE - 1` for `beta`.
Therefor `if(score < alpha) {` or `if(score < beta) {` will always be false for every step, that does not call a base case.
Your recursion looks something like this:

- depth = 4, call depth = 3

  - depth = 3, call depth = 2

    - depth = 2, player1 won, score is 42
  - depth = 3, update alpha = 42, return beta = `MAX_VALUE - 1` as score
- depth = 4, call3 returned `MAX_VALUE - 1` which is my beta so nothing changed, `bestR` and `bestC` stay -1

Comment: At the moment I'm first trying to make it works with a 3x3 board. I included the generateMoves function only because it can be the origin of the exception put out of bounds is in the result of the finally algorithm when I try to put execute the resulting move that being [-1][-1] it goes out of bounds. To clarify when I do `field[cMove[1]][cMove[2]] = nComputer;` after calling the function. Thanks anyway for the answer and sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: I updated the code with the suggested improvements but it still return the same result as before